# Block camera for video call using android service

Tags: android, service, camera, block

I want to block camera when other apps try to open it.
I have created one service which opens a window whenever other apps try to open a camera but in the case of video call it is not working as expected.
Overlay window is showing whenever camera gets opened but in video call, the caller can see my face because there is only an overlay window over camera but camera does not get blocked completely.

Here is the code to block camera :

```
public class AppOverlayService extends Service
{
    public Window window;
    private CameraManager cameraManager;
   

    public AppOverlayService() {
    }

    private final CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback cameraCallback = 
    new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraUnavailable(@NonNull String cameraId)
        {
            super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
            window.open();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraAvailable(@NonNull String cameraId)
        {
            super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
            window.close();
        }
    };
    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        window = new Window(this);
        
        cameraManager = (CameraManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        cameraManager.registerAvailabilityCallback(cameraCallback, null);
    }
}
```

So I need a logic to block the camera through service.

Comment: A device manager app can disable the camera, with user permission, [on some versions of Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager?hl=en#setcameradisabled). No app should be able to unilaterally block the camera, as that would be a significant security flaw.

Comment: I want to block the camera without using device admin permission. There are many apps in the play store which are doing the same thing so it is possible.

Comment: That's disturbing. Perhaps I will find them and bring them to Google's attention. Do you have any examples? While I can certainly see some privacy value, there are other options for that (such as physically covering the camera aperture). And there are many scenarios where malware might love the ability to block a camera against the user's wishes (biometrics, dashcams/personal security cams, lost-device trackers, etc.).